# How to make our own public dedicated server in Don't Starve Together which will run 24/7?

Tags: hosting, dont-starve-together

I always seen in Don't Starve Together (Online version) there is one or two world that have a dedicated server. In dont starve together game, you have to make your own "world" in-game or i would say a "room" by creating a server in your PC or you could just try to enter other people server/room.

When i tried to create my own server ( i usually play with my friends, like 2-3 friends ), i have to kept my computer with Don't starve together game running to make the room/world in-game playable. It's pain in the ass since i am not online 24 hours to play this game, while in the other hand, my friends play time is not the same as my play time. So when i could play in certain days, my friends couldn't and *vice versa*.

When i saw other room that people made, there is called a "dedicated server" which is a room that would be online 24/7 straight. How could i make these kind of room/server ? Do i have to pay for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many years, i finally know that if you want to run a server that run 24/7, we need to rents or use hosting site for minimal 3.99 or 9.99 dollar/euro to running a server for a months.

1. https://server.nitrado.net/usa/offers/dont-starve-together
2. https://nodecraft.com/games/dont-starve-together-server-hosting

Answer (score 3):

In your Steam library, there's a search bar in the upper left. To the right, you'll see 'games'. Click that, then in the dropdown, select tools.

Locate 'Dont Starve Together Dedicated Server', install it, and run it. This is the dedicated server program that is used to keep servers up and running 24/7. It allows a world to exist without a player being there.

I'd recommend against installing and running this on a machine that is typically used for everyday work or gaming, though.